# How to set a cookie in JSTL

Tags: cookies, jstl

I am trying to achieve the below but not sure if its possible and what should the syntax be ?

```
<c:if condition is true>
  <c:set cookie using JSTL>
</c:if>
```

I am thinking ,since cookie is only set on client side and JSTL is used for doing things on server side, it cannot be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't set a cookie using JSTL. [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) doesn't have any tags for this functionality. JSTL runs during generating the HTTP response, while a cookie needs to be set in the HTTP response header long before generating the HTTP response. There's otherwise means of an illegal state.

Use a preprocessing [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) or [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) instead wherein you can just call `response.addCookie()`

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for your answer. I thought the same, but wasn't too sure. Just wanted to confirm.